# Estimate GARCH model in EViews after removing missing data

Tags: missing-data, garch, error-message, eviews

I want to estimate **daily stock prices** and **natural gas data** with using **GARCH in EViews**. There are some missing days (like holidays etc.). When I extract them from the data set, ARCH is not working. Would you please *kindly* assist me to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: When I run the GARCH model on E-views, "ARCH needs continous sample" error is seemed.

Comment: That makes sense. The estimation method used in EViews for GARCH models likely cannot handle missing data. And it makes sense, because you cannot just delete the missing data points and pretend they were never there; that messes up the time dependence. A dirty method to deal with this would be data imputation. A clean method would be to use another estimator that can handle missing data, but that can be hard to implement. What % of your data is missing? If it is low (say, 1%), then data imputation should not cause much of a problem.

Comment: I have 2505 observation and 90 of them are N/A . What about I use the closing price of the last day? It'd be dirty method, wouldn't it?

Comment: That is something that can considered. Why are these observations missing?

Comment: Just because the bank holidays, I guess (because 4th of July etc. are missing)

Comment: In such a case it might be worth trying to make EViews believe the data with missing values removed are in fact consecutive (as if the missing values were never there). But I don't know how to do that, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried that, it gave the same error. I guess I'll go with the same closing date with the previous one. But thank you! You really tried to help me, it means alot.

Comment: You are welcome! I find helping other people quite meaningful. Good luck with your analysis!